# How to handle error conditions in a void function

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm making a data structures and algorithms library in C for learning purposes (so this doesn't necessarily have to be bullet-proof), and I'm wondering how void functions should handle errors on preconditions. If I have a function for destroying a list as follows:

```
void List_destroy(List* list) {

    /*
      ...
      free()'ing pointers in the list. Nothing to return.
      ...
    */
}
```

Which has a precondition that `list != NULL`, otherwise the function will blow up in the caller's face with a segfault.

So as far as I can tell I have a few options: one, I throw in an `assert()` statement to check the precondition, but that means the function would *still* blow up in the caller's face (which, as far as I have been told, is a big no-no when it comes to libraries), but at least I could provide an error message; or two, I check the precondition, and if it fails I jump to an error block and just `return;`, silently chugging along, but then the caller doesn't know the `List*` was NULL.

Neither of these options seem particularly appealing. Moreover, implementing a return value for a simple destroy() function seems like it should be unnecessary.

**EDIT:** Thank you everyone. I settled on implementing (in all my basic list functions, actually) consistent behavior for NULL `List*` pointers being passed to the functions. All the functions jump to an error block and `exit(1)` as well as report an error message to `stderr` along the lines of "Cannot destroy NULL list." (or push, or pop, or whatever). I reasoned that there's really no sensible reason why a caller should be passing NULL `List*` pointers anyway, and if they didn't know they were then by all means I should probably let them know.

Comment: Could you throw an exception...?

Comment: Either have the function guard against the failing case (possibly logging it for later analysis), or make darned sure the calling code never provokes the failing case (as you said, it's a precondition; document it as such), or have it return a success/failure indication even if you don't always check it (fairly common), or build an exception-like mechanism using setjmp/longjmp. 

C doesn't protect the programmer as much as some languages do. You do have to be careful when using it.

Comment: @Eric it's C code, so there's no exception for me to throw.  My only options are to blow up with a segfault, my own error message, or silently continue without doing anything like free() does when passed a NULL pointer.

Comment: void functions should report precondition violations by not being void functions :)  In all seriousness, as a library creator you have two responsibilities: create bullet-proof code, even when abused; and clearly indicate when something goes wrong.  The first implies your function should detect the NULL list (or possibly any non-list pointer) and the second could either be clear documentation, a return code (which will inevitably be ignored) or an assertion.  Depending on the criticality of your domain killing the application may not be advisable (think pacemaker, etc).

Comment: I suppose I will go with the do-nothing solution, that seems reasonable to me. I will, however, log a warning message (or error, not sure how strongly I should word it..?) noting that a NULL pointer was passed. By the way, does there exist a runtime macro similar to `__FUNCTION__` that is instead the calling function? That would be useful information to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructors (in the abstract sense, not the C++ sense) should indeed never fail, no matter what. Consistent with this, `free` is specified to return without doing anything if passed a null pointer.  Therefore, I would consider it reasonable for your `List_destroy` to do the same.

However, a prompt crash would *also* be reasonable, because in general the expectation is that C library functions crash when handed invalid pointers.  If you take this option, you should crash by going ahead and dereferencing the pointer and letting the kernel fire a SIGSEGV, *not* by `assert`, because `assert` has a different crash signature.

*Absolutely do not* change the function signature so that it can potentially return a failure code.  That is the mistake made by the authors of `close()` for which we are still paying 40 years later.

Comment: Could you explain how this is related to `close`? A close may fail for good reasons, I think.

Comment: @mafso Close *shouldn't be able to fail*, because there is no sensible way to recover from the failure, and because you-the-programmer need to be able to deallocate a file descriptor no matter how screwed up its device driver has gotten.  This is a special case of the general observation that destructors in general, and resource deallocation functions in specific, must not ever fail.

Comment: And what should happen, if the device holding the file to be closed is removed physically while the program is run or something like that? The program should at least be able to log that failure, shouldn't it? Just because there is no good way to recover from that error, it doesn't mean that the application should not have been told about it. You always have the freedom to ignore the return value...

Comment: I would generally agree with the "destructors mustn't fail" but returning an error code isn't nescessarilly the same a failing.  Yes, the cleanup should complete...but you should also be able to warn the user that something wicked this way comes.

Comment: I suppose I will go with the do-nothing solution, that seems reasonable to me. I will, however, log a warning message (or error, not sure how strongly I should word it..?) noting that a NULL pointer was passed. By the way, does there exist a runtime macro similar to `__FUNCTION__` that is instead the calling function? That would be useful information to report.

Comment: Nothing portable.  If you are really curious there are diagnostic utilities that can evaluate a stack trace at runtime.  They are often fragile and easilly befuddled by certain optimization settings.  For example: [Microsoft's StackTrace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @mafso The current thinking is that that sort of error should be reported by `write` or `fsync`, and that if you call `close` without first calling `fsync` you are abandoning your interest in whether there was a delayed failure.  I agree this is not ideal, but the cure is proper filesystem transactions, not allowing a resource-deallocation interface to fail.

Comment: @Dalton I wouldn't advise splitting the difference like that.  Either do-nothing on NULL is part of the API, in which case the programmer should be allowed to rely on it, or it isn't, in which case you should crash.

Comment: @Zack: That seems to make sense; I'm not sure, if `fclose` can fail (except with `EBADF`) after a successful `fflush` call. And I'm still not sure if there isn't any reason that a failure should be possible. Anyway, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have several options if a constraint of one of your functions is violated:

1. Do nothing, successfully
2. Return some value indicating failure (or set something pointed-to by an argument to some error code)
3. Crash randomly (i.e. introduce undefined behaviour)
4. Crash reliably (i.e. use `assert` or call `abort` or `exit` or the like)

Where (but this is my personal opinion) this is a good rule of thumb:

- the first option is the right choice if you think it's OK to not obey the constraints (i.e. they aren't real constraints), a good example for this is `free`.
- the second option is the right choice, if the caller can't know in advance if the call will succeed; a good example is `fopen`.
- the third and fourth option are a good choice if the former two don't apply. A good example is `memcpy`. I prefer the use of `assert` (one of the fourth options) because it enables both: Crashing reliably if someone is unwilling to read your documentation and introduce undefined behaviour for people who do read it (they will prevent that by obeying your constraints), depending on whether they compile with `NDEBUG` defined or not. Dereferencing a pointer argument can serve as an `assert`, because it will make your program crash (which is the right thing, people not reading your documentation should crash as early as possible) if these people pass an invalid pointer.

So, in your case, I would make it similar to `free` and would succeed without doing anything.

HTH

Comment: So I ended up implementing (in all my basic list functions, actually) consistent behavior for NULL `List*` pointers being passed to functions. All the functions jump to an error block and `exit(1)` as well as report an error message along the lines of "Cannot destroy NULL list." (or push, or pop, or whatever). I reasoned that there's really no sensible reason why a caller should be passing NULL `List*` pointers anyway, and if they didn't know they were then by all means I should probably let them know.

Comment: @Dalton: Consistent behaviour is good :) I, personally, would not write to any stream which is not passed in by the caller (at least, not in a library), but `stderr` is OK, I think (but still: don't spend too much time on people not reading your documentation, you cannot serve them better than by letting their applications crash as early as possible).

Comment: Indeed, the messages are written to `stderr`. I have some macros I use for debugging, checking preconditions, et cetera, all of which write to `stderr` if they do report anything. Thank you for the help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish not to return any value from function, then it is good idea to have one more argument for errCode.

```
void List_destroy(List* list, int* ErrCode) {


*ErrCode = ...
}
```

Edit: 
Changed `&` to `*` as question is tagged for C.

Comment: Aiiieee! Never, ever, ever do that, not even in functions that *aren't* destructors.  It is worse than `errno`.

Comment: Um... Can you please elaborate whats wrong with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out-parameters are bad in general.  Out-parameters that are error codes are extra bad, because they contort the caller's control flow.  You are inviting people to write `int dummy;` at the top of the function, pass it into each call, and then not bother checking it, and the compiler won't ding you for it.  (Also, you can't use `int&` in C, but that's a detail.)

Comment: @Zack: I don't think, this represents good coding style, but your argument is nonsense: If the caller of your function doesn't care for errors, she just wouldn't care, no matter how the error is told to the caller. There is no reason to take care for programmers who write bad code and don't care about errors.

Comment: @Zack I have changed output argument to * from &(sorry for that). But still I am not able to understand why output parameters are bad!.. if you can give me example or some link pointing out the same would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that simply returning in case the list is NULL would make sense at this would indicate that list is empty(not an error condition). If list is an invalid pointer, you cant detect that and let kernel handle it for you by giving a seg fault and let  programmer fix it.

Comment: By this you will not trap multiple error codes.  Also list null could be a valid case.